# use part of classname in jQuery code

Tags: jquery, jeditable

This is my existing code to save changes to my database with an select with jEditable

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$('.editable_select').live('click',function(){
  $('.editable_select').editable('includes/js/save_to_db.php', { 
      tooltip   : '<?php echo $lang['tooltip']; ?>',
      event     : 'dblclick',
      data   : '<?php print json_encode($select_bet_termijn); ?>',
      type   : 'select',
      submit : 'OK',
      style  : 'inherit',
     submitdata : function() {
    }
  });
});
</script>

    <?php td colspan="2" class="editable_select" id="adressen|betalingstermijn_id|'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['betalingstermijn_id'].'</td> ?>
```

What I want to achieve is to rename the class to editable_select|select_bet_termijn and use this class at 2 positions in the jEditable code:

- editable_selec = name of class
- select_bet_termijn = name of data (= 
  array)

How can I split the class name using the | seperator and insert the new varibales [0] / [1] in the code?

Comment: Just use two classes. `class="a b"` then check for `$(".a.b")`

Comment: If I use 2 classes I still have to use different codes for each select.

Answer (score 0):

According to [CSS Grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner), using a pipe `|` in a class name is invalid, so instead I changed your split identifier to `-_-`.  That being said, using a simple javascript [`split`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method almost gets you the result you require, using it multiple times to account for cases where there are more than one class on our element:

```
$(some_selector).live('click',function(e){
  var tClass    = $(this).attr('class');
  var aClass    = tClass.split('-_-');
  var aClass0   = aClass[0].split(' ');        // split on ' ' to separate
  var aClass1   = aClass[1].split(' ');        // multiple classes
  var class1    = aClass0[aClass0.length - 1]; // and then choose our
  var class2    = aClass1[0];                  // class names

  $('.' + class1).editable('includes/js/save_to_db.php', { 
      tooltip   : "<?php echo $lang['tooltip']; ?>",
      event     : 'dblclick',
      data      : '<?php print json_encode($' + class2 + '); ?>',
      type      : 'select',
      submit    : 'OK',
      style     : 'inherit',
      submitdata: function() {
                  }
  });
});
```

I'm not sure if I understood your requirements precisely, but this should get you there.

Comment: This seems what I'm looking for but I'm getting an error at <?php print json_encode($' + class2 + '); ?>' Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'

Comment: Ok, I don't think you can do what you're trying to do because the php exectues on the serverside before the Javascript, but this functionality relies on the opposite being true.